# How add LocalDate list to myList in Java

Tags: java, types, date-parsing, localdate

How add Local date list to myList in java

Please find the below code and check where I made a mistake to add dates to myList

I declare List as Local date now need to convert to myModel

error occurs in //  myList.addAll(employeeReportsModel.getReportFromDt());

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getMusterRollDateBased", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getMusterRollDateBased(EmployeeReportsModel employeeReportsModel) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    String tablePrefix = "at_hr_logs_";

      try {
       System.out.println("refort from date.."+employeeReportsModel.getReportFromDt());

        System.out.println("refort to date.."+employeeReportsModel.getReportToDt());
        String fromdate = employeeReportsModel.getReportFromDt();
        String todate = employeeReportsModel.getReportToDt();
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fromdate);
        Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(todate);
        System.out.println(date1 + "-----" + date2);            
        // parse the date into another format           
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");           
        String fromdate1 = sdfDestination.format(date1);
        String todate1 = sdfDestination.format(date2);          
       employeeReportsModel.setReportFromDt(fromdate1);         
       // get dates between two dates           
       String startString = fromdate1;          
       String endString = todate1;

       LocalDate incrementingDate = LocalDate.parse(startString);
       LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(endString);
       List<LocalDate> allDates = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!incrementingDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
            allDates.add(incrementingDate);
            incrementingDate = incrementingDate.plusDays(1);
        }

        System.err.println(allDates);
        List<EmployeeReportsModel> myList = null;   
        mv.addObject("allDates",allDates);
        for (LocalDate date : allDates) {
            //System.out.println();             
            System.out.println("dates is..." + date);
            employeeReportsModel.setReportFromDt(date.toString());              
            String[] parts = date.toString().split("-");
            String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
            String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
            System.out.println("year ....." + part1);
            System.out.println("Month....." + part2);

            String tableName = tablePrefix + part1 + '_' + part2;
            System.out.println("hks table name is.." + tableName);
            employeeReportsModel.setDynamicTableName(tableName);
            myList.addAll(employeeReportsModel.getReportFromDt());
          //here we get a problem to add
}

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mv.setViewName("/" + moduleName + "/employeeMusterRollBasedOnDateInter");
    return mv;

}
```

Comment: What is the problem, do you have any error message ?

Comment: The method addAll(Collection<? extends EmployeeReportsModel>) in the type List<EmployeeReportsModel> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: When you can use the modern and better `java.time` API, for example `LocalDate`, there is no reason why you should also want to use the old, outdated and troublesome classes like `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. The modern API offers all the functionality you need.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException error occur

Comment: Thanks for providing more information, @chalam. When doing so, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51020665/edit) and at the information there. In the case of an exception, as here, include the stacktrace in the question and format it as code, then it will be nice and readable for everyone. Thanks for helping us help you.

Answer (score 3):

First thing is that you call `myList.addAll()` on a null object. Your list should be initialized properly like `myList = new ArrayList()`.

Then you are trying to store a String type in your list which expects an object of type EmployeeReportsModel.

So you either change your myList to look like `List<String>` or change your return type of the `getReportFromDt()` method.

I suggest you to rethink your current code.

Currently you are basically doing the following:
get a local date > create a String out of it > store it with setReportFromDt > call getReportFromDt > try to store LocalDate in string form into a List of type EmployeeReportsModel